# Как убрать верхний отступ html?

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка, header

```css
*,html{
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
  }
/* Шапка */

header {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(57, 27, 115);
    background: linear-gradient(5000deg, rgba(57, 27, 115, 1) 0%, rgb(124, 13, 158) 100%);
    border-radius: 0 0 80% 80% / 0 0 50% 50%;
}

.header_content {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 13%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    width: 60%;
}

.header_content span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.header_content h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 60%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.header_content h2 span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.header_content p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    width: 55%;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.header_content a {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #0287EC;
    padding: 11px 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.header_content a:hover {
    background-color: #EE4E64;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header_content">
            <span>CREATIVE</span>
            <h2>Performing <span>Brilliantly</span> to boost your business</h2>
            <p>Creativity provides a unique point of difference for your brand and that is what we do best.</p><br>
            <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня нет никакого отступа сверху

Comment: Если судить по скрину у вас там еще есть некоторая шапка от cms
А если вглядеться что это похоже вп
в коде что вы скинули ошибки нет
Смотрите другие стили
это вп двигает контент под свою шапку